# How to set script only run one times? Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

For example. new tab and include website is the same url

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @include  https://stackoverflow.com/
// @grant    GM_openInTab
// ==/UserScript==

var curTab  = GM_openInTab ("https://stackoverflow.com/");
```

visit SOF.com after than open more one SOF.com new tab

Comment: Please post appropriate code snippet detailed

Comment: same as the example. just not this url. thank you

Comment: anyone know this question?

Comment: The question and example are not clear. The code duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/ but what is the goal?

Comment: hi erosman,i want to visit stackoverflow.com 2 times, and extra open 1 times stackoverflow.com new tab.

Comment: Still not clear. Visit 2 times how often? for ever? each session? each window? each hour?

Comment: um, Not so complicated. Just visit SOF.com then open more one SOF.com new tab.

Comment: What about the next time you open SOF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not clear enough for a definite answer. Here is a script example based on available information:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name          One Time
// @description   Open New tab one time
// @match         https://stackoverflow.com/
// @grant         GM_openInTab
// @author        erosman
// @version       1.0
// ==/UserScript==

if (!localStorage.getItem('oneTime')) {
  
  localStorage.setItem('oneTime', 'true');
  GM_openInTab('https://stackoverflow.com/');
}
```

Comment: hi,erosman. thank for your help.
how about if i open one more newtab(SOF.com) run same script?

Comment: @Mrjai  It is a different question so better to post it separately.

Comment: can you please help me?thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62913789/how-to-run-script-in-specify-tab-and-not-effect-the-other-side-tabgreasemonkey