# How to run script in specify tab, and not effect the other side tab(Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey)

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

How to run script in specify tab, and not effect the other side tab?

like first tab keep going auto-refresh example.com

as the same time new tab visit example.com(Non auto-refresh)?

#Greasemonkey #Tampermonkey

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Auto-Refresh
// @include  https://www.example.com
// ==/UserScript==

setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear enough for a definite answer.

User-scripts normally do not have access to TAB data to know which tab they are running on.

Among user-script managers (GreaseMonkey, ViolentMonkey, TamperMonkey & FireMoneky), ATM only TamperMonkey has `GM_getTab` & `GM_getTabs` API (Non-standard) to get details about the tab that script runs on. Therefore such solution would only work on TamperMonkey.

Furthermore, the `location.reload()` also makes it more difficult.

Is that the real code or `location.reload()` is just an example?

Comment: about location.reload() just simply every 5 seconds refresh one times. as the same time can open one more newtab to visit example.com.